# Как в WooCommerce добавить кастомное поле к цене?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я создал кастомное поле второй цены в WooCommerce и разместил его под базовой ценой.

```
/* Выводим поле аренды при создании товара */
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'art_woo_add_custom_fields' );

function art_woo_add_custom_fields() {
global $product, $post;
echo '<div class="options_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
    'id'                => '_text_field',
    'label'             => __( 'Rental ($)', 'woocommerce' ),
    'placeholder'       => 'cost of rent per day',
    'desc_tip'          => 'true',
    'custom_attributes' => array( 'required' => 'required' ),
    'description'       => __( 'cost of rent per day',
    'woocommerce' ),
) );
echo '</div>';
}

/* Сохраняем значение аренды в базе данных */
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'art_woo_custom_fields_save', 10 );

function art_woo_custom_fields_save( $post_id ) {

$woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
if ( $woocommerce_text_field ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );
}
}

/* Выводим аренду в карточке товара */
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'art_get_text_field_before_add_card' );
function art_get_text_field_before_add_card() {
global $post, $product;
$text_field     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );  
if ( $text_field ) {
    ?>
    <span class="text-field">
        <strong>Rental: </strong>
        <?php echo $text_field; ?> 
    </span>
<?php }
}
```

Как мне теперь сделать, чтобы обе цены были в одном ряду?

Мне нужен вот такой вариант - $200 retail / $20 rental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте фильтр `woocommerce_get_price_html`:

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $_this ) {
    $text_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
    ob_start();
    if ( $text_field ) {
        ?>
        <span class="text-field">
                <strong>Rental: </strong>
            <?php echo $text_field; ?>
            </span>
        <?php
    }
    $text = ob_get_clean();
    return 'Retail: ' . $price . ' / ' . $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вроде все работает )